# How to use multiple links in one cell in html

Tags: html, html-table, cell

My question is that how  can I use multiple link in one cell?

My html view is this and I want to have link on home, products and contact us.

My homework is design a website with table:

[image]

My code is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<table style="width:100%" border="1px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" bordercolor="green" bgcolor="yellow" height="500px">
<caption>web design homework</caption>
<tr>
<th colspan="3">My Website</th>
</tr>
<tr  bgcolor="#77E022"
height="20px" align="left" >
<td  colspan="3" >  home  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   products   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   contact us  
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="25%"> last post </td>
<td rowspan="2" width="50%"> hello my name is mohammad ghorbani and i am studying computer enginerring in arak </td>
<td> our friends </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> our statics </td>
<td> 24 </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is really necessary doing layout coding with table? Its 10+ years tech.

Comment: it's homework man . i haven't choices.

Comment: Clearly you have no idea about front-end development. Check out HTML, CSS and JavaScript on w3schools.com

Comment: @ebilgin why w3schools? MDN docs are much better.

Comment: @0x860111 Because its great for beginners compare with MDN. If you have an idea what front-end development is, you should check MDN.

Answer (score 2):

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" bordercolor="green" bgcolor="yellow" height="500px">
  <caption>web design homework</caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">My Website</th>
  </tr>
  <tr  bgcolor="#77E022" height="20px" align="left" >
    <td  colspan="3" >
      <a href="/home">home</a>
      <a href="/products">products</a>
      <a href="/contact">contact us </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%"> last post </td>
    <td rowspan="2" width="50%"> hello my name is mohammad ghorbani and i am studying computer enginerring in arak </td>
    <td> our friends </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> our statics </td>
    <td> 24 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add links to your text, for example change:

```
contact us
```

to

```
<a href="www.google.com">contact us</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this maybe:

```
<a href="url1"> home </a>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   <a href="url2"> products </a>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   <a href="url3"> contact us </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add anchor tags and below css

```
 <a href="#">home</a>
 <a href="#">products</a>
 <a href="#">contact us </a>
```

Css:

```
a { 
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="home">home</a>
  <a href="products">products</a>
  <a href="contact">contact us</a>
```

Use the above code to replace the below one

```
<td  colspan="3" >  home  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   products   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   contact us
```